# Front-channel logout URL is not called when Sign out everywhere is done in incognito window

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal, single-logout

I have created a multitenant application in the Azure Portal. I have set its redirect URIs and Front-channel logout URL.
[image]

I opened a normal(not incognito) Chrome window and I give consent to my application with a Microsoft account. Then I opened another incognito Chrome window and went to https://myaccount.microsoft.com/(it redirect me to sign in page firstly) after that I clicked to Sign out everywhere button. However any request come to API that listen to GET requests of Front-channel logout URL so I could not clear any datas from the database.

However if I open the another Chrome window withhout incognito mode, a request is always comes to API that listen to GET requests of Front-channel logout URL if Sign out everywhere button is clicked.

So, why a request is not sent when I am using incognito window? I expect that Microsoft should know the logged in session and send a request for it even if the Sign out everywhere action is done in another incognito session.

The general guide I am following for this is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/

The specific guide is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-sign-in?tabs=java#sign-out

The example project that I am use it for making practicing: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapi/tree/master/msal-web-sample

The button that I am clicking and could not get a GET request to my front channel logout url which is set in my application page on Azure Portal when I try to click that button in a different incognito window or different browser window is shown below:
[image]

Comment: Did you open and log into your web application after navigating to https://myaccount.microsoft.com/ and before clicking Sign Out Everywhere button in your incognito Chrome window?

Comment: @SergeyKhutornoy 
I open and log into my web application in a normal Chrome window.

Then I opened another incognito Chrome window and I went to  myaccount.microsoft.com in that incognito window. After that I clicked the Sign out everywhere button which is in the myaccount.microsoft.com page. So the problem is occured(which I mean, Microsoft does not send any request to Front Channel Logout Url which is set in the application page on Azure Portal)

Comment: I'm guessing something is being tracked in a cookie which is not available in the incognito window - i.e. session-level stuff like client logins are not tracked in the backend against the user.